# Selenium: How to get text from within an html tag which has another tag in it

Tags: html, css, selenium

```
<a class="spf-link current" href="/orders/returns?offset=0&limit=25">
<span class="pg-helpText">Page</span>
1
</a>
```

I need to read the value '1' in my test. When I do a get text using css-selector .spf-link.current, it gets me "Page 1". I only need '1'. How do I exclude the text from the span tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need Javascript [childNodes](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_childnodes.asp) to get the text from the nodes.

> The childNodes property returns a collection of a node's child nodes,
> as a NodeList object.
>
> The nodes in the collection are sorted as they appear in the source
> code and can be accessed by index numbers. The index starts at 0.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By
                           .cssSelector(".spf-link.current"));
String node_text=(String)((JavascriptExecutor)driver)
                           .executeScript("return arguments[0].childNodes[2].nodeValue",element);
```

This should give you the value 1 as `node_text` when you run the JavascriptExecutor. Other way is to split the text `Page 1` on the basis of `space`. But, i would prefer `childNodes`.

Let me know if you have any queries.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

//span[@class="pg-helpText" and contains(text(), 'Page')]/following-sibling::span/span

Comment: These numbers are actually link to different pages and every link has a similar span. I need the one specifically in <a class="spf-link current"> which shows the current page

Answer (score 0):

It is not normal to customize untagged text between tags.

I recommend you to change the value to your desired result:

```html
<a class="spf-link current" href="/orders/returns?offset=0&limit=25">1</a>
```

...and when you want to show it in other place, do it as `var ThePage = "Page " + [the page number]`

Other solution is to include it into another tag as a `div` or as another `span` with a different class or id.